# Collapse values for other columns based on unique values on one columns

Tags: windows, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

I want to go from:

```
ind  col1 col2 col3
1    12   333  string1  ...
2    23   444  string2 ...
3    34   555  string1 ...
4    13   667  string2 ...
5    17   888  string3 ...
...  ...  ...  ...   ...
```

to:

```
ind  col1    col2        col3
1    12,34   333,555  string1  ...
2    13,23   444,667  string2 ...
3    17      888      string3 ...
...  ...  ...  ...   ...
```

If I do this :

```
df.groupby('col3').agg(','.join)
```

This will modify the structure of the table by using the col3 as the index. I would like not to modify the table structure and have a result identical to the above table (including col3)

```
          col1     col2
col3                   
string1  12,34  333,555
string2  23,13  444,667
string3     17      888
```

Comment: try adding `.reset_index()[df.columns]` ...?

Comment: df.groupby('col3').agg(','.join).reset_index().. it works!

Answer (score 1):

Try passing in arg `as_index=False`, this will keep 'col3' in the aggregated `DataFrame`. Then index with `df.column` to fix the column order:

```
df.astype(str).groupby('col3', as_index=False).agg(','.join)[df.columns]
```

[out]

```
    col1     col2     col3
0  12,34  333,555  string1
1  23,13  444,667  string2
2     17      888  string3
```

Comment: @Popo thanks for the suggestion, I updated my answer. Cheers again

Comment: Thanks for taking the time :)